# How can I run some code after success register, allauth, Django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I use allauth package for login and register users and for social registration/authorization. And I want to subscribe user to email newsletters after success register(including social registration).

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can listen to signals:

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def login_fb_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    socialuser = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=user, provider="facebook")[0]
    # here login success
```

[and here](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html) are all list of signals

Comment: Thanks. But -  "logged_in" - Is it for sign up users. I want to subscribe only once after registration

Comment: There's a `user_signed_up` signal as well. The docs has a [list of signals](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html#allauth-account).

Comment: @Q-bart in your models.py :)